# How can I fix this small regex?

Tags: regex

I am pretty weak writing RegExp here is what I'm trying to match:

```
foo.123
foo.bar.456
anything.here.again.999
```

In fact, I need to match as many `[a-z]` founds, seperated by one `.` character and finally, a number of 3 characters length.

Here is my RegExp: `^([a-z\.]{1,})([0-9]{3})$` the problem is that it does match:

`foo.bar111` or even `foo..bar.111` is being matched.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What *flavor* of regex are you using? They vary.

Comment: This is for Javascript's RegExp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below regular expression. Note the `\.` outside of the character class:

```
^([a-z]+\.)+([0-9]{3})$
```

`{1,}` can also be replaced with `+`.

Answer (score 2):

Match start of the string, any number of lower-case letters followed by a dot, and finally any 3 digits followed by end of line:

```
^([a-z]+\.)+\d\d\d$
```